# Secure Boot - Custom signed bootloader

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, digital-signature, secure-boot

Through Secure Boot on Windows 10, I am trying to make it so that only a bootloader signed with my private key can boot on a machine. This means that  even if someone else comes along with a Microsoft trusted OS with all the digital signatures, it should fail to boot because it was not signed with my private key. As for the reason why I want to do this, I was told to do so I must find a way.

What I have done is deleted the firmware keys (PK, KEK, DB, DBX) in my BIOS, and enrolled my own public keys which I generated using OpenSSL. I then created a bootable USB disk using Rufus, signed the Windows bootloader, `bootx64.efi`, using `sbsign` with the corresponding private key (DB.key) effectively replacing Microsoft's signature with my own.

But when I try to boot via the USB, I get a blue screen with the following error:

> The digital signature for this file couldnt be verified
>
> Error Code 0xc0000428

It does not say which file though so I thought I had to sign all the .EFI binaries and then put them on the USB disk which is what I did but the same error occurred. I also tried disabling Secure Boot and see if that would change anything but it still gave me the same error.

How can I get this to work? Am I missing something else here?

Comment: You might be able to get a Linux OS to accept your own certificate but you will be unable to get Windows 10 to accept it.  **There is no way to enable Secure Boot and boot to Windows 10 using your own certificate.**  You have been told to make the impossible happen.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks your reply. Is there any article stating this online somewhere?

Comment: There are a ton of articles indicating what had to been done in order to get various Linux distributions to work with Secure Boot and Windows 8+ working.  Linux could careless which certificate is used, it's the Windows boot loader, that expecting to be able to verify the certificate chain.

Comment: @Ramhound So if I were to get Microsoft to sign my bootloader with their private key (in which the public key is used for the existing trusted certificates), would it work then? In that case, that would still allow anyone with a Windows 10 OS to still boot right?

Comment: Yes;  That’s exactly what the Linux community had to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed write a custom bootloader, custom signed by you.
Allow the efi to only boot that.
Your custom bootloader must then verify and load a second stage bootloader (microsoft's one) signed by microsoft